# Unable to archive in iTunes Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, itunes-store, cfbundleidentifier

When trying to upload my app, I get the error:
"You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request". The identifiers (UTI format) in info.plist, "General Identity", iTunesConnect and App ID (Apple Developer) are all similar.

When getting the CFBundleIdentifier in applicationdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: I get the same result.

I have changed the project name, maybe it has something to do with that?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

[image]

[Info.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rb3Y.png)

Comment: No app name wont make any changes for it. Check the CFBundleIdentifier in your project its empty or invalid. In plist , set Bundle identifier value as '$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)' and check it.

Comment: Thanks. Still the same problem. I have added a screenshot of Info.plist. Am I missing some items? The location of Info.plist in Build Settings is correct.

Comment: You can able to archive successfully for production?

Comment: Exporting is possible, validating is not.

Comment: Hey, did you figure it out?

Comment: Apple checked my ip, no problems in there. They advised to not use the beta version of XCode and add some missing app icons.

For me this was not the solution. I solved it but don't know how, probably it had something to do with the entitlements file (also in .plist).

Comment: "ip" has to be ".ipa"

Comment: @JeeGee I am also facing same issue. Have you got any work around?

Comment: Has anyone resolved this issue yet?

Comment: anyone got solution?

Answer (score 12):

I was getting this error when free space in my mac hard disk was low

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error. In my case, the .ipa was put inside a folder. But, since i used the file-extension ".ipa" when Xcode asked me to where to put the output, the file was put inside a package. Once i exported the archive again and only used a name for the output everything worked fine.

Comment: @brandonscript He suggested a solution. Please read until the last word.

Answer (score 4):

Open your `info.plist` and check to see if `Bundle OS Type code` is `null`. I had the same problem, and added `APPL` to `Bundle OS Type code`, and it was OK.

See here for a [helpful image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mwrnw.png).

Answer (score 2):

Change **Bundle OS Type code** and **Bundle creator OS Type code** to APPL.

It probably won't work. :-(

Restart XCode. Now it works :-)

Comment: Adding Bundle OS Type code to Info.Plist and changing both Bundle OS Type Code and Bundle creatorOS Type code to APPL worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and resolved it the following manner. First make sure that this is not related to information in the info.plist - as outlined in the other answers - make sure that `Bundle OS Type code` is set to `APPL`. This was not the issue for me.

With Xcode 8 and later, Go to [developper.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com) and remove all iOS provisioning profiles **and** iOS certificates. Then in Xcode go to Preferences. Select your Apple ID. Click on view details. 
Right click on Provisioning profiles and either delete them directly or open in Finder and delete them.

Close Xcode. Re-open. In your project, in general, uncheck Automatically manage signing. Recheck it so that Xcode creates the new provisioning profile.

Check the signing and make sure you are using newly created profile, as shown here:

[image: profile details]

Good to go!

Answer (score 0):

For Me It was all about checking Requires Full screen that option for iPad mainly .. and the error happen cause you may checked 3 Orientations for all devices .. but the iPad in multi-tasking is requiring the whole 4 orientations..

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had ***two info.plists*** sitting silent in finder.
 After deleting one I also had to change:
***Bundle OS Type code*** from ***BNDL*** to ***APPL*** 
No idea how the changes happend in the first place, but now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using someone's else certificate and provisioning profile to archive app, sending him IPA file and he was uploading it to Apple Store. It resulted in this same error, the fix was to send whole dictionary with "ExportOptions.plist", "DistributionSummary.plist", "Packaging.log" and IPA.

Answer (score 0):

I had that exact problem with my react-native app built using expo. Believe it or not, just restarting the Application Loader fixed the problem. :)

Mine was a react-native app built using expo.