# You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, phonegap

My app Already on itunesconnect but I need to upload a new Build.
I am use build.phonegap.com
when I try to upload the new Build , I can see this message 
"You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request"
How can I fix this Problem?
Thank you

[image: You must supply a CFBundleIdentifier for this request]

[image: iOS Provisioning Profiles]

[image: plist file]

Comment: 1. Do you have free space on your Mac ? 
2. Maybe your provisioning profiles is invalid. Check your developer account and delete it to recreate a new one
3. Is your file a .ipa ?

Comment: Check for the distribution certificate and provisioning file, they must be valid. If any of them is invalid, then this error message can be show.

Comment: Check this link who explain my number 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38749623/unable-to-archive-in-itunes-store/41589775#41589775

Comment: 56.09 GB avilable,

Comment: Status:
    Active
Expires:
    May 29, 2018

Comment: .ipa ? yes it is , by build.phonegap.com